# Storing multiple downloaded images from database - PHP

Tags: php, sql, file, download

I have various images split in the database as blob files. I have written a php script which accesses these blob files and downloads them locally.

As there are many images I have put an loop which would download all images which are stored in the database, however when I run the script in the loop I get one big download and no separate images.

My code is as follows:

```
$query="SELECT `id` FROM `images` LIMIT 10";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$imageid = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
//iterate over all the fields
foreach($row as $key){ 
    $imageid[] = $key;
    }
} 

$fileName ='';

for ($i = 0; $i < count($imageid); $i++) {

    $query="SELECT `filename` FROM `images` WHERE `id`=".$imageid[$i]."";

    $result=mysql_query($query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        foreach($row as $key){ 
            $fileName = $key;
        }
    } 


    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); // set expiration time
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0,pre-check=0");

    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename='.$fileName.'');

    $sql = "SELECT `data` FROM `images_data` WHERE `image_id`=".$imageid[$i]." ORDER BY id";    
        $result1=mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) echo $row['data'];




}//END FOR LOOP
```

Is there any way I can download all of the images from running the script? 
If I manually change the parameter of $imageid[$i] (eg 0,1,2,3 etc) the different images will download but its useless for the amount of images I have to use.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: just like to throw a comment in. please dont store images as blobs within a database, it makes the database incredibly bloated and hard for the db server to use efficiently, store the images as files and store their file name within the database

Comment: +1 to @bizzehdee, any sql database is not suited for this use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get only on file once from one php script run. 
In you case I think best way is, store all files from DB into temporal folder, when zip (or GZ) this folder, and after output this ZIP (or GZ) archive using corresponding MIME type in you header()